# Why isn't my select box generator displaying all options in the table?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a select box generator(called ListGenerator) which needs to take the option names from a table called categories and add them to the select box. The database is also updated from a form which allows the user to enter a new option to be added to the select box.

Currently the generator only takes the last inputted name and displays it in the select box. I believe the generator is getting the result straight from the form rather than the query? Below is the code for the INSERT of the data from the form to the table and the query which should SELECT everything from the table and put it in the select box.

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $result= $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO categories (name) VALUES(:name)');
    unset($_POST['submit']);
    $result->execute($_POST);
}

$ListGenerator =new ListGenerator();
$categoryresults = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM categories'); 

foreach ($categoryresults as $row) {
    $ListGenerator->setList([$row['name']]);
} 

echo $ListGenerator->getHTML()
```

The code for the ListGenerator is below, this works fine when inputting fixed strings into the ->setList function in the above code:

```
<?php   
        class makelist{
        public $list;
        }





        class ListGenerator {
        public $makelist = [];

            public function setlist($list){
                $this->makelist = $list;
            }

            public function getHTML(){
                $result = '<select name="category">';



                foreach ($this->makelist as $list) {
                $result = $result . '<option>' . $list . '</option>';
                }




                $result =$result . '</select>';

                return $result;
            }

        }

            ?>
```

Comment: No one can help without seeing the code in `ListGenerator` class

Comment: I don't really know how your ListGenerator works but it seems weird that it would be able to guess the identifier from the categories table. Secondly, I dont really understand what your question is.

Comment: I don't see the result set being fetched anywhere

Comment: Updated the question to include the code

Comment: Still doesn't actually fetch the resultset by the looks of things

Comment: **1)** You replace the `makelist` array every time you add a new item. **2)** You never fetch the result (`$categoryresults->fetchAll()`) **3)** When you get `makelist` to actually add items instead of overwrite them, you wont be able to output an array as a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested but I think it ought to fetch the results something like this?

```
$categoryresults = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM categories');
$listitems=array();

while( $rs=$categoryresults->fetch( PDO::FETCH_OBJ ) ){
    $listitems[]=$rs->name
}
$ListGenerator->setList( $listitems );
```

Comment: This actually works, after fixing a small syntax error! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well, if it works - accept the answer so others in the future might also find this as a solution?